# Javascript get element background image BUT eliminate the "url()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ive been working on an image gallery ive been creating myself and im adding a "Zoom in" feature to it.

I know im very close to succeeding but i have just one tiny issue.
In Javascript i managed to get the background property of the image that will be enlarged but it grabs the image including the `url()`. I want to only get the URL (http:.../) EXCLUDING the `url()`.

I hope this isn't very confusing but if you are, this is the link to my project. Click on the image to Zoom in, but it actually alerts the `background-image` property because i wanted to see what it fetches first.

[Check it out](http://cssdeck.com/labs/hzzzvem7)

Is this possible?

Comment: Checkout my answer @xR34P3Rx, using regular expressions is the most safe way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution is the [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) method. The first parameter specifies where to start the selection, the second specifies the end the selection from end of string if it's negative. So, your code should be:

```
var bkImg = window.getComputedStyle(sourceimg,null).getPropertyValue("background-image");
var bkImgUrl = bkImg.slice(4, -1);
```

Comment: just about the same as Alejandro's. Kudos to both of ya'll and everyone who helped!

Answer (score 1):

---

UPDATED

You can use a regular expression to take off the `url(` and the `)` like this:

```
  var sourceimg = document.getElementById("image");
  var url = window.getComputedStyle(sourceimg, null).getPropertyValue("background-image");
  var urlWithoutUrl = url.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
  alert(urlWithoutUrl);
```

:)

Comment: I wouldn't call that a regular expression, because it's static. And also it will replace all `)` parentheses, even if the image filename itself has them.

Comment: and now? :P @AlejandroIván

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to just take the string inside the `url()` rather than using regular expressions or other stuff.

```
var url = "url(somefile.gif)";
var final_url = url.substr(4, url.length - 4 - 1);
```

Arguments: The initial position (starting from `0`, that means fourth character is "s") and the number of characters that will create the new string (that is, the length of the original string minus 4 -the `url(` stuff- and minus 1 -the `)` stuff-).

The result will be:

```
somefile.gif
```

Using it in your problem:

```
var url = window.getComputedStyle(sourceimg,null).getPropertyValue("background-image");
var final_url = url.substr(4, url.length - 4 - 1);
alert(final_url);
```

Comment: This is the cleanest code of most of the others. Thanks, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression, or substring from the position of

```
s.IndexOf("(")) + 1;
```

Thake everything after the "URL(" and then trim the last character to remove the ")".

Comment: How could i implement this in my code?

    `function viewFull(){
    var sourceimg = document.getElementById("image");
    var fetch =        window.getComputedStyle(sourceimg,null).getPropertyValue("background-image").IndexOf("url(");
    alert(fetch);
}`

this is what i tried

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var url = $(el).css("backgroundImage").split(/\s|url\(|\)/).filter(Boolean)[0];
```

```js
var url = $("body").css("backgroundImage").split(/\s|url\(|\)/).filter(Boolean)[0];
console.log(url);
```

```css
body {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/200/technics/')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the change you need to make in code:

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(sourceimg,null).getPropertyValue("background-image").replace(/^url\((http.+)\)$/g, '$1'));
```